# Match "next day" using forecast() in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am working through the "Forecasting Using R" DataCamp course.  I have completed the entire thing except for the last part of one particular exercise (link [here](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/forecasting-using-r/advanced-methods?ex=3), if you have an account), where I'm totally lost.  The error help it's giving me isn't helping either.  I'll put the various parts of the task down with the code I'm using to solve them:

> Produce time plots of only the daily demand and maximum temperatures with facetting.

```
autoplot(elec[, c("Demand", "Temperature")], facets = TRUE)
```

> Index `elec` accordingly to set up the matrix of regressors to include `MaxTemp` for the maximum temperatures, `MaxTempSq` which represents the squared value of the maximum temperature, and `Workday`, in that order.

```
xreg <- cbind(MaxTemp = elec[, "Temperature"], 
          MaxTempSq = elec[, "Temperature"] ^2, 
          Workday = elec[,"Workday"])
```

> Fit a dynamic regression model of the demand column with ARIMA errors and call this `fit`.

```
fit <- auto.arima(elec[,"Demand"], xreg = xreg)
```

> If the next day is a working day (indicator is 1) with maximum temperature forecast to be 20°C, what is the forecast demand? Fill out the appropriate values in `cbind()` for the `xreg` argument in `forecast()`.

This is where I'm stuck.  The sample code they supply looks like this:

```
forecast(___, xreg = cbind(___, ___, ___))
```

I have managed to work out that the first blank is `fit`, so I'm trying code that looks like this:

```
forecast(fit, xreg = cbind(elec[,"Workday"]==1, elec[, "Temperature"]==20, elec[,"Demand"]))
```

But that is giving me the error hint "Make sure to forecast the next day using the inputs given in the instructions."  Which...  doesn't tell me anything useful.  Any ideas what I should be doing instead?

Comment: It'd probably be more helpful if you tried this in Rstudio, etc., so you could see the actual error and not the hint. A statement like `elec[,"Workday"]==1` will produce a boolean vector. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @cmaher It doesn't produce a syntax error - DataCanp tells you if your code does so. It just doesn't produce the result they are after, and I am not clear on what result they actually want in order to debug.

Comment: `elec[,"Workday"]==1` and `elec[, "Temperature"]==20` don't give you a subset of `elec` and nor do they assign values to those columns (`==` is never used for assignment); instead, they compare all of the values in those columns to the values `1` and `20`, respectively. To subset `elec` where `Workday` equals `1`, you'd use elec[elec["Workday"] == 1,]. In this case, however, it seems that you're supposed to provide values for `xreg`'s covariates like so: `MaxTemp`, `MaxTempSq`, and `Workday` like so:  `forecast(fit, xreg = cbind(MaxTemp = 20, MaxTempSq = 400, Workday = 1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are forecasting ahead of time, you use new data that was not included in `elec` (which is the data set you used to fit your model). The new data was given to you in the question (temperature 20C and workday 1). Therefore, you do not need `elec` in your `forecast`call. Just use the new data to forecast ahead:

```
forecast(fit, xreg = cbind(20, 20^2, 1))
```

Comment: Ah, I knew I must be missing something obvious. That worked. Thanks so much!